# Обрезка строки и приведение ее к JSON типу

Tags: c#

Хочу распарсить html, в котором находиться JSON, чтобы затем его записать в базу.

вот как выглядит html

```
 <div class="bContentColumn"> 
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
 Core.Namespace.exp('Pages.Detail.modelData', {"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]});
 Core.Namespace.exp('Pages.Detail.useFakeSaleBlock', false);  </script> 
 </div>
```

**Количество данных в Json, может быть разное.**
 До div я добираюсь очень просто

```
string div_inner_text = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='bContentColumn']").InnerText;
```

Дальше начинаю резать строку, по первой запятой, которая в строке встречается

```
string result = div_inner_text.Substring(div_inner_text.IndexOf(',') + 1);
```

Начало я получил, но вот как мне взять окончание JSON?
Пробывал так

```
string res_two = result.Substring(0, result.IndexOf(';'));
```

Но этот вариант мне не нравится,потому-что привязка к точке запятой не надежна и вообще может встречаться в тексте. Ну вот вопрос, как мне максимально красиво вырвать из diva Json?

Comment: Почему бы вам сначала html-парсером не найти скрипт, а потом уже парсить его?

Comment: (Хотя, если вы пытаетесь получить информацию с сайта, который не предоставляет API, то это всё равно напрасный труд, как мне кажется: сайт имеет право поменять формат в любую секунду.)

Comment: там много скриптов в этом файле

Comment: Да это OZON сомневаюсь , что они скоро все сменят. У них есть XML, но он меня не устраивает в виду не полной информации по товару

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал таким образом: 
Достанем сначала содержимое тега script:

```
string div_inner_text =  htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='bContentColumn']").ChilNodes[0].InnerText;
```

теперь удалим из него все отступы/табуляции/переносы:

```
div_inner_text=div_inner_text.Replace("\n","").Replace("\t","").Replace("\r","");
```

И получили мы строку которая всегда начинается с 'Core.Namespace.exp('. Можем это начало удалить:

```
div_inner_text=div_inner_text.Remove(0, 18);
```

Начало нашли. Осталось найти конец. И достать данные

```
var json_data=div_inner_text.Replace("});","|").Split('|').First()+"}";
```

Вероятность того что в данных встретиться строчка '});' и '|' маленькая. Вариант далеко не идеальный, но мне много раз помогал.